# Zend Framework Multi Module Access?

Tags: zend-framework

I have two modules in my application Admin and Default (Shopping Cart).

In My Admin Module I have added 3 Controllers Products, Category and Users

I want to add 3 Links in My Layout but it will cause error

Links to be added as:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index'), 'admin', true); ?>">Products</a>
```

When I Click on This Link It will show me error

`Message: Route admin is not defined`

Give Answer with Example

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include how and where you are defining the admin route?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to the url view helper is for the router name.  If you haven't defined a custom router, then you don't use it.  What you need to do, is put 'module' in the array for the first parameter, like this:

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('module'=>'admin','controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index')); ?>
```